# Kafka Consumer returns null value

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

I am trying to make a kafka consumer in Java but the `consumer.poll(5000)` method call return null value no matter what. here is the code:

```
package com.apache.kafka.consumer;


import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;

public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class);
          //Kafka consumer configuration settings
          String topicName = "mytopic";
          Properties props = new Properties();
      
      
           props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
           props.put("group.id", "test");
           props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
           props.put("auto.offset.reset","earliest");
           props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
           props.put("key.deserializer", 
           "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
           props.put("value.deserializer", 
           "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
           props.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "range");
           KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new 
           KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
   
      //Kafka Consumer subscribes list of topics here.
      consumer.subscribe("sampletopic");
      while (true) {
          Map<String,ConsumerRecords<String, String>> records = consumer.poll(0);
          for (ConsumerRecords<String, String> record : records.values()) {
              System.out.println(records);
          }
     }
}
```

}

Please help!!!

I have created the topic already and also have added some data in it plus the zookeeper and kafka are running perfectly. I don;t know why the `poll()` method is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `poll` needs to be in a loop, that's why the literature calls it *the poll loop*.

If its returning `null` its either polling too early and exiting the `main` or no data is in the topic

See the usage examples here https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

```
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
     props.setProperty("group.id", "test");
     props.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true");
     props.setProperty("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
     props.setProperty("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     props.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
     while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
             System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
     }
```

Notice the loop ^

Comment: Ok I did as you said but I'm still getting null. I have checked also kafka and zookeeper are running and the topic "mytopic" has values in it.

Comment: Can you update you question then, with you new snippet with the loop? Also notice you don't have a `value.deserializer` set like the example

Comment: thanks for being patient with me, i have edited the code with the loop now and also added the `value.deserializer`  still null pointer exception.

Comment: I solved it! It was basically dependency problem but after that I applied you solution to it and it works like a charm thanks man!